# Configure jersey RESTFUL using xml

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, spring-aop

I would like to ask you about RESTFUL with jersey api;whenever we are doing annotaion based configuration in spring for example of its Aspects we can use Annotation or xml based configuration.

```
@Aspect in class
```

**or**

```
<aop:aspect></aop:aspect> in xml
```

Is there any option available like this in `RESTFUL with jersey api` with seperate xml?

```
@Path("/hello")
public class RestHelloWorld { 
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 // method
}
```

**to**

some xml configuration for these path,method and other annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Jersey is an implementation of `JAX-RS`, so looking at the `JAX-RS` specification (downloadable [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html)) first, there is no mention of any XML configuration mechanism. Instead the specification clearly states that it is **POJO-based**:

> The API will provide a set of annotations and associated
>   classes/interfaces that may be used with POJOs in order to expose them
>   as Web resources. The specification will define object lifecycle and
>   scope.

Reading through the [Jersey user guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html), it seems that Jersey (as expected) does not add on an XML configuration mechanism of its own.

So, it looks like it's going to be annotations all the way. In general, it seems that as far as JavaEE is concerned, XML configuration mechanisms are slowly going the way of the dodo.

Comment: Thanks for Enlightment it was really helpful.